# VueX Mutation Optimization

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, javascript-objects

I am working with a VueX store at the moment, and I have 1 mutation that does a push to entire array. Everything works currently, but want to know if I can make this code simpler, less lines / more optimized at the same time.
*Side note, these are objects stored in an array.*

```
PUSH_TO_ALL: (state, data) => {
    const found = state.all.find((one, i) => {
      if (one.slug === data.slug) {
        state.all[i] = data // modify current state
        return true
      }
      return false
    })
    if (!found) {
      state.all.push(data) // add to the state
    }
  }
```

Comment: `find`, etc aren't supposed to contain side effects, they weren't designed for that. If you need to get `i`, this is what findIndex is for. Also Vue reactivity ignores direct changes in arrays like `state.all[i] =`, be aware of this.

Comment: @EstusFlask Are yo able to explain why the state ignores the `state.all[i]` ? As it does seem to work, is something going to break. Or might you have an alternate solution to what i'm thinking with this?

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays . Depends on how you use `all`. You may not notice it at all. Use `splice` to replace an element or possibly replace `all` entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is that if you compare the `slug` in `data` to that in every object in the array, it must be unique (otherwise you would replace multiple objects in the `find`).

This means that you can almost certainly make things a lot faster and a lot simpler if you switch from having the 'root' of state be an array, to using an object instead, indexed by `slug`.

Then your code would switch to being something like:

```
PUSH_TO_ALL: (state, data) => {
    state.all[data.slug] = data
```

This has 2 advantages - it is much simpler and faster to modify state, since you don't need to walk all of state checking if the object already exists. And secondly there's no need for separate code to distinguish between adding a new object, and replacing it if it already exists.

If for some reason you have to store state as an array, I would use a different part of state to maintain an object which tracks `slug` to array index.  Then your code would be something like:

```
PUSH_TO_ALL: (state, data) => {
        if (state.map[data.slug]) {
          state.all[state.map[data.slug]] = data
        } else {
          // Push returns length of array - index is len-1
          state.map[data.slug] = state.all.push(data) - 1
        }
```

*Note* - in Vue2 you may need to use `Vue.set()` to update nested objects, since otherwise the code may not react to these changes. Vue3 no longer has this limitation.

Comment: Hey @match, the issue with the first option, which I quite like. Is if you use string based key's, the Array.length will always be zero. Kind of becomes messy with that happening. I store the data as an array so I can loop through it well. What's your thoughts with that?

Comment: @match `state.all[0] = data` doesn't look right. That should be `state.all[state.map[data.slug]] = data`.

Comment: Thanks - not sure where that came from! Have updated the example.

Comment: @match, is there any downfall to storing data as an Object, or an array for looping? IE: https://jsfiddle.net/jona0ey3/

Comment: The main disadvantage is that you potentially use more memory storing data as a key - however it will be much faster for keyed lookups. I believe arrays are faster to iterate than objects, but that probably isn't significant.

Comment: Thanks @match for your insight. With a blend of both these answers, I was able to make it work. And for anyone else that might view this page, make sure to use Vue.set() to keep your object reactive, otherwise your state won't be adjusted on the front-end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Array.findIndex instead of Array.find, and pair it with a ternary to make the trivial logic more concise (though not necessarily clearer).

```js
const mutations = {
  PUSH_TO_ALL: (state, data) => {
    const indexOfMatchingSlug = state.all.findIndex(one => one.slug === data.slug);
    state.all[indexOfMatchingSlug] = data ? indexOfMatchingSlug > -1 : state.all.push(data);
  }
}
```

[Array.findIndex documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

[JavaScript ternary operator documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)